# Find a function $f$ such that $f'''(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}{x}}}$

Tags: calculus

> Find a function $f$ such that $f'''(x) = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+\sin^{2}{x}}}$.

I am confused how to solve this since we would have to integrate this three times. My book says there is an easy way of solving it and to not misinterpret the word "find".

Comment: $ 1 + \sin^2x =\cos^2 x $ is not true. And you can't integrate that expression without expressing it in terms of elliptic integrals.

Comment: What does the book mean by easy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We make use of the formula

$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^x f(x)(x-u)^2 du = \int_{0}^x \int_{0}^x \int_{0}^x f(x) dx dx dx $$

to get that $\displaystyle f(x) = \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^x \dfrac{(x-u)^2}{\sqrt{1+\sin^2{u}}}du$.